# Passing variable from ajax to php and it is not being passed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to pass a variable value to php on same page using onClick

I have been searching google for days and trying all the examples and can't get anything to work

```
<!doctype html>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    echo $YourName= $_POST['name'];
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function msg(){

      var name = "JR"; 

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data:  {name : name},
      cache: false,
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);
      }
    })
 }
    msg(); 
</script>
<button type="button" onClick="msg();">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

should pass value to the php part of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the url in ajax of same page.

If it's in same page, after getting the response use die. otherwise you will get complete HTML code in response. and it should be on top of page.

example.php file will be like.

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    echo $YourName= $_POST['name'];
    die;
}
?>
<!-- now start html code -->
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function msg(){
    var name = "JR"; 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'example.php',  //Add the url of same page
      data:  {name : name},
      cache: false,
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
        $('#results').html(data);
      }
    })
 }


</script>
<div id="results"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="msg();">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you add the url. And follow the step what i mention

Comment: did you try? your updated code is working. just add div to display the result on page. like - <div id="results"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="msg();">Click Me!</button>

Comment: I got it to display in the div.  But what about in the php it's not echo the name there.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I finally got it to work just like I needed.

Comment: Glad to help you..) if it's working as you expected please mark this ans